# How to add image with text into UIAlertView?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uialertview

I want to add image with some text into UIAlertView like given image below [image]

Here is my code

```
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Please use Settings(    ) to configure the phone number and image." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160.5, 27, 15, 15)];

    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"settingIcon.png"];

    [alert addSubview:imageView];

    [alert show];
```

But image is not showing inside alertview. Your help will be appreciable. Thanks

Comment: I checked your code ... its working with my image... just check your image name..

Comment: check UIImageView frame

Comment: I have check all frame as well as image name but still it is not showing. It was working with first version but now suddenly this code stop working.

Comment: **160.5** - hell no. You round up or down, never halfway.

Answer (score 9):

It is emoji. You can find the entire unicode of emoji's here: [Emoji Unicode](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode)

You can use the unicode of corresponding image to show that in your alert like:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Midhun" message:@"\xE2\x9C\x88" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
[alert show];
```

Comment: Thanks Midhun  for your reply , But i don't want to add Emoji unicode images . It must be my settingIcon.png image.

Comment: @chandan: Then you can use the `[alert addSubview:yourImageView];`

Answer (score 2):

try this In IOS 6

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Please use Settings(    ) to configure the phone number and image." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160.5, 27, 15, 15)];
        
        NSString *path = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"settingIcon.png"]];
        UIImage *bkgImg = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
        [imageView setImage:bkgImg];

        [alert addSubview:imageView];

        [alert show];
```

i hope this will help u

If you are use in IOS 7 , We can not add the Image in IOS 7 Because In IOS 7 Remove all addSubview Functionality....So can not add the Image in IOS7.

Comment: This worked great for me over the past year or so - but now with ios 7, the image is no longer visible.  Any idea what the move to iOS 7 may have had to do with this?