# custom popup screen in iOS app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios5, popup

I am new to iOS app development.

I want to develop a popup screen, that should popup when a button is pressed. In this popup I want to show a Login screen, where user will enter username and password and will submit the credentials. I have following requirements to be fulfilled.

1. It should support all iOS 5.1 and upwards.
2. It should also support any device orientation.
3. It should work for both iPhone and iPad.
4. It is to be delivered in the form of a library `.a file`.
5. It will contain a logo(image) also.

I am not able to find out how should i proceed for this, for BB10 I have used `sheets` for the same purpose.

Any suggestion on how to develop this for the iOS apps.

thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17698571/how-can-i-create-a-custom-popup-window-for-iphone
There are many way available.

Comment: The condition of "It should support all versions of iOS." is impossible. You can only support 4.2 and up. But IRL you should only support iOS 6 and up.

Comment: I want to support from iOS 5.1 and upwards.

Answer (score 1):

For your first three requirements will fulfill by adding `textfields` into `alertview` and for 4th creating library kindly see this [Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/41377/creating-a-status-library-in-ios-tutorial). Hope it'll help. Thanks.

Comment: I have came to know that in iOS 7, we cannot add an image to the `alertview` [SOURCE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16714053/how-to-add-image-with-text-into-uialertview). Is there any other option ?

Comment: Just FYI, `UIAlertView` is [deprecated](http://nshipster.com/uialertcontroller/).

Answer (score 0):

@mayank  http://code4app.net/category/popupview  it contains many project for pop up view it will help you!